# c# datatable select statement with dates

Tags: c#, datetime, select, datatable

i am trying to make a select statement on a datatable to get the row that is within the date range i am looking for. I am new to this an i dont quite understand how this select statement works. I tried to write this but is not working. Can you please give me a hand here. I am stuck

```
foundRows = dt.Select("DATE1 <= '" + date1+ "' AND DATE2 >= '" + date1+ '"');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides wrapping your dates with #, if date1 is a DateTime and not a string, you need to use the ToString(your date format) to get the correct sql statement.  For debugging it make it easier if first you create a string containing your filter, then do the select using that string.  Then you can look at the string and use that in the query builder to validate your sql.

Comment: ok i got it. string testing = date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = dt.Select("DATE1 <= '#" + testing+ "#' AND DATE2 >= '#" + testing+ "#'");
                
                decimal value1 = System.Convert.ToDecimal(foundRows[0][0]);

Comment: what happens in the case that the select doesnt contain anythin. ex. the date is outside of the boundaries?

Answer (score 13):

This the Best Optimal Search Criteria I have Tested.
you having to dates.

From_Date = 12/01/2012
To_Date = 12/31/2012

and Your column in DataTable upon which you applying . (in my code 'date')

Your Select Statement will be like this.

```
  DataRow[] rows = newTable.Select("date >= #" + from_date + "# AND date <= #" + to_date + "#");
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer on this post.

[DataTable Select by exact DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454586/datatable-select-by-exact-datetime/55523301#55523301)

You can use a similar approach by using ticks to select in a range.

Answer (score 0):

Using this inside an SSIS script component. I just used the example from above that included "#" around the dates. Also I converted each to string. This worked perfectly.

Just in case you want to know how I setup this up inside SSIS:
First had a data flow using the recordset destination with an Object variable to store the recordset.

in my script I included the variable as a read only.

In the main class...

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter();
System.Data.DataTable AwardedVacTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
...
...
```

then in Pre-Execute...

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    a.Fill(AwardedVacTable, Variables.rsAwardedVac);
...
...
```

then in a custom method accessed the datatable ...

```
String dtFilter = "EmployeeID = " + empId.ToString() + " AND (#" + Convert.ToString(StartDate) "# <= EndDate AND #" + Convert.ToString(StartDate) + "# >= StartDate" + " OR #" + Convert.ToString(StartDate.AddDays((double)numDays)) + "# >= StartDate AND #" + Convert.ToString(StartDate.AddDays((double)numDays)) + "# <= EndDate)";

DataRow[] Overlaps = AwardedVacTable.Select(dtFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

expression = "Date > #2015-1-1#";
DataRow[]  foundRows = table.Select(expression);
与
select * from tablename where Date>'2015-1-1'