# Filtering results within a DataTable (date column between date1 and date2)

Tags: c#, datetime, date, datatable

I am using c#, sqlce, datatable. I select products with this query:

```
select price from products where productid=myproduct and mydate between startdate and finaldate and clientid=myclient
```

But it's going to take much time.
So I could use a datatable to store products:

```
datatable prices = new datatable(); 
prices=this.returntable("select productid,startdate,finaldate,client from products")


 for(int i=0;i<allproductsihave;i++) {
    product.newprice=this.getmyprice(prices,product.client,product.id,product.date);
 }


 private decimal getmyprice(datatable products,string myclient, string myproduct, datetime mydate)
 {
   //how do I do at here the equivalent to first sql query?
   //for select a product from a datatable where my date is between 2 dates,
   //and client=myclient and productid=myproduct
   return Convert.Todecimal(datatable.prices[something]["price"].tostring());
 }
```

In this way I shouldn't connect to the database for each product query.
Is it posible?

> maybe doing convert.todatetime to startdate and finaldate?

Comment: Why would the query take a long time?  Create an index on productid,clientid,startdate.  They whatever you do in C# isn't going to go any faster, is it?

Comment: well my boss doesn't want queries, he wants it is as i have described

Comment: Your boss isn't a programmer is he? Doing this in code is not scalable as you are loading the entire table into memory. That results in a whole lot of unnecessary network traffic and unneeded memory consumption. In addition the iteration via for loop means that every element must be iterated, regardless of whether it meets the criteria or not. Add to that the fact that you're using a (probably untyped) DataTable and every element you test is going to result in an unboxing operation. This is a huge timewaster. You'd be far better off letting the database do what it's designed for.

Comment: here is the link of the work:
[The Code For Date Filtering][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619601/1147352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method accepts a string representing a "where" condition and returns an array of DataRow containing matching rows.

```
Datarow[] products = prices.Select(string.Format("'{0}'>='{1}' AND '{0}'<='{2}'", mydate, startdate, finaldate));
```

Mind the date format!! It must be sql compliant.

Comment: what is mydate here?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you dont want to make multiple requests to the database because you are worried about making several connections, which will be slower?  If you dont want to connect for every product, why not just use a "where product in ('xxx', 'yyy')" instead?  Then you have a single query call, and no changes on the database.  You can then process the results when you get them back.

Your boss should speak to @pilotcam.  He is right.  Its no quicker in c# than it would be on the database. :)

In fact, doing this in c# means you are getting information back (I assume over a network if its a remote database) which you would never use, so its probably slower, how much depends on how much data is in your database which wont be in your final results!

Answer (score 1):

As much as I disagree with this method for reasons stated in comments, here's one possibility.  The idea here is to check for the most obvious exclusions first, then work your way to the date later.

```
    private decimal GetMyPrice(DataTable table, string client, string product, DateTime date)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row["productid"] != product) continue;
            if (row["client"] != client) continue;
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(row["startdate"]) < date) continue;
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(row["finaldate"]) > date) continue;

            return Convert.ToDecimal(row["price"]); 
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();               
    }
```