# DataTable Select by exact DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I have a DataTable `xData` which has a `DateTime` column with millisecond accuracy, I need to extract the rows which match an exact time with milliseconds but cannot get the syntax correct.

I've tried

```
DateTime dt = timeStampList[i];
string str = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
DataRow[] result = xData.Select("TimeStamp2 = " + str);

foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[1]);
}
```

but

```
DataRow[] result = xData.Select("TimeStamp2 = " + str);
```

causes an error:

> Syntax error: Missing operand after '16' operator.

I've searched but most of the examples only show how to select by date and not a full `datetime` with milliseconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have to pass the date/time you're looking for to your filter.

At first I thought that sub second precision was not supported by `Select` but according to Dmitry's answer it is.

Another approach is to use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to avoid serializing the date/time:

```
DateTime dt = timeStampList[i];

IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = 
  xData.AsEnumerable().Where(row => (row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp2") == dt));

foreach (DataRow row in selectedRows)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[1]);
}
```

Comment: +1, your approach is much better because it doesn't use strings.

Answer (score 6):

If the `TimeStamp2` column has the `DateTime` type, you should surround your `DateTime` string with the `#` char:

```
DataRow[] result = xData.Select("TimeStamp2 = #" + str + "#");
```

See the [Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) section.

If the type of `TimeStamp2` column is a `string`, enclose a value into quotes `'`:

```
DataRow[] result = xData.Select("TimeStamp2 = '" + str + "'");
```

**EDIT**
A sample code for the `DateTime` column type:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A", typeof (DateTime)));
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10);
table.Rows.Add(dt);
table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("A = #" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "#");
```

Result: one `DataRow` in the `rows` variable.

Comment: @vc74 Why? I've tried it for the `DateTime` column. It works.

Comment: interesting, I tought it would not. I didn't see anything in the doc that said sub second precision was possible but according to your example it seems to work. +1

Answer (score 0):

I too have had problems using the DateTime literal when concerned with the accuracy upto nano seconds. ***If possible***, you can try to use the long datatype in your table and compare DateTime using `DateTime.Ticks`. This makes the select queries relatively very easy.

Your query would just translate to

```
DateTime dt = timeStampList[i];
long dtTicks = dt.Ticks;
DataRow[] result = xData.Select("TimeStamp2 = " + dtTicks);
```

I found this method effectively easy in case of searching between date ranges as well.

If you happen to return the value as a DateTime it can be easily done as

```
return new DateTime(valueInTicks);
```

Comment: A negative vote without an explanation? My solution solves the OP's problem. Since the datatable is an in-memory data structure, it can be modified I think.