# DataTable select method with Dates not showing right result

Tags: c#, .net, datatables

I have a Datatable with rows that i need to remove and insert into another Datatable. I am selecting the rows where column SLA < than todays date (SLA < '#date#'). When i do this the data in my new Datatable is not correct. I am getting rows that have dates that are later than todays date. I dont know what i am dowing wrong. The SLA column date syntax is **dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm**.

Here is my code:

```
public SLAWarningHandler()
{
}
public DataTable SLAWarningData(DataTable queryData)
{
    DataTable data = queryData;
    try
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DataRow[] rows = data.Select("SLA < '#" + date + "#'");
        DataTable actual = new DataTable();
        actual = data.Clone();
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            actual.ImportRow(row);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have tried to convert the date parameter to a string like so:

```
date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
```

but that didnt help.

Can anyone point out my issue?

thanks!

Comment: What is your data provider?

Comment: You need to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934615/c-sharp-datatable-select-statement-with-dates

Comment: @SonerGönül Data provider is Ole DB

Comment: @sdeep i have been looking at the link you sent, but u cant see how my code is different from his.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you return wrong thing. You have to return Actual but you return data that is original record set.

```
public DataTable SLAWarningData(DataTable queryData)

    {
        DataTable actual = null;
        DataTable data = queryData;
        try
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            DataRow[] rows = data.Select("SLA < '#" + date + "#'");

            actual = data.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                actual.ImportRow(row);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        return actual;
    }
```

Comment: also you may not to create the empty `DataTable` as you clone the original data: DataTable actual = null;

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard ISO format (yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss):

```
DataRow[] rows = data.Select(string.Format("SLA < '{0}'", date.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Or:

```
DataRow[] rows = data.Select(string.Format("SLA < '{0}'", date.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
```